# PHP preg_replace &nbsp;

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm stuck with this one...

I insert some data into a database table which comes from a form. Sometimes, this data contains html, so I do

```
$note = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db, $_POST['note']));
```

I then store the $note in my database. When retrieving my notes, I check whether there is html code in it, and if there is, I want to have it highlighted using `highlight_string()`. That part works like a charm. Now here's the problem:

I am displaying the highlighted string in a div container, but it's overflowing because the white spaces are being converted to `&nbsp;`. I'm trying to remove those non-breaking spaces and replace them with a simple space so the highlighted string will be contained in the div.
I have tried this so far:

```
$note = html_entity_decode($note);
$note = highlight_string($note);
$note = preg_replace('/&nbsp;/', '', $note);
```

I have also tried `$note = str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $note);`, to no avail.

Any help is very much appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: Send TRUE as second parameter to `highlight_string` for it to return the value

Comment: Try saving your data like this first and then try to see output. See if it works: htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db, base64_encode($_POST['note'])));

Comment: @RolenKoh Don't throw more junk on the fire. It is entirely unnecessary to base64-encode the data.

Comment: Oh. No. `htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string(NO))`. *Do not use HTML escaping to "protect" database access*; use escaping *only* when applied to the context for which it was applied - in this case that would mean using htmlentities *when* output as appropriate, and *not before*. At the very least, use mysqli_real_escape_string (MRES) last prior to building the SQL string. If MRES doesn't make the data safe, then applying HTML escaping won't do any good. But better, don't even use MRES - [use parameterized queries](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/2864740).

Comment: user2864740 I am using mysqli_real_escape_string() to escape the data that will be put into my database. Then I run htmlentities() in that.

Comment: @chaensel If using MRES (but really, *use placeholders*) do `$insert_this_exactly = MRES(htmlentities($raw_data))`. That is, *only the result of MRES* is guaranteed safe when used as a string literal content in SQL command text. However, I would do `MRES($raw_data)`. Then you have the *real data* in the database, not some encoded junk that won't add any "security" against SQL injection - and has to be decoded later on! When displaying use `echo "<span>" + htmlentities($original_raw_data) + "</span>";` or whatnot. That is, only encode *for* a specific context *when used* in that context.

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks for the thoughts. I will keep that in mind when working on this script. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is quite simply that `highlight_string()` is outputting its result immediately, rather than saving it to `$note`.

Instead, please try the following:

```
$note = html_entity_decode($note);
$note = highlight_string($note, true);
$note = str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $note);
```

The difference in my code is that I use `highlight_string($note, true)` with the second parameter set to true. The [docs](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php) shed some light about the function's behavior:

> mixed highlight_string ( string $str [, **bool $return = false** ] )
>
> **Return**
>    Set this parameter to TRUE to make this function return the highlighted code.

The regex function you have in your code block might work, but since this is a simple replacement, it will suffice to use `str_replace` in this case, as you have tried.

Comment: Thank you very much @ljacqu! Setting the second parameter of `highlight_string()` to `true` worked for me.

I also had to add some CSS to override the default <code> layout. I did the following in my CSS file:

`code {
 display: inline-block;
 max-width: 100%;
 white-space: normal;;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with strip_tags in place of htmlentities

```
string strip_tags( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )
```

In allowable_tags, you can define the html you want to allow in string. If null it will not allow any html to get apply.

Reference : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php